# Adding a namespace to my permanent library in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, customization, using

I am trying to add a custom namespace to my permanent library so that I can us it any future project. I want to just add "using MyNameSpace;" to be able to access it whenever needed. How would I go about doing this, if at all possible? I have looked every place I could think to look, but have come up with nothing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You add

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
```

after all global `using` or import/include directives, in all files. Then add the terminating

```
}
```

at the end.

Do this for all source/header/etc. files.

Comment: This does not help. I know how to do it for one project, but how do save it for all future projects without having to import it each time.

Comment: @Makai So you want to change the Visual Studio templates used for new C++ (or whatever language you use) files to automatically include this for you?

Comment: How do I do that? Where do I go?